# Imported vector object from Illustrator to PhotoShop is blurry

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an object created in ***Adobe Illustrator***, I copied this object to ***photoshop*** as a *Smart object*.

[image]

However, when zooming in or saving, its edges are not smooth!
[image]

PS:

- The object is imported to PhotoShop as a smart object.
- The *Anti Aliasing* option is checked at the transformation panel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the vector information still in tact if you edit the smart object, or did it convert it to a raster image?

Comment: No, it is still a smart object and hasn't been rasterized :(

Comment: So if you open the smart object, the vector image returns and the object is sharp again, right? A smart object is like a placeholder for an actual image. It creates a rasterized preview for editing, but should be converted and have higher quality when exporting to .png etc

Comment: Yes, when double-clicked it opens at *Adobe Illustrator* for editing and it is intact.

Comment: Yes, this is as design then. The smart object in photoshop is a placeholder. If you copy and paste it as a vector object instead, it will be smart, but you may have to spend some time to get it correct.